# Openlayers 3. Aspect ratio question

Tags: openlayers

This image has size given as 1920 x 1080 
[image]1080

This image has size given as 2000 x 2000
[image]

They are the same map, so the image is distorted. What ratio would the height & width need to be to give the correct aspect ratio? There can only be one correct aspect ratio!!

This is the code that makes the map:

```
    var cabinet = this.getTheCabinet();
    var center = this.transformCoordinates(cabinet.geoLocation);
    //Initialize the view, this can be changed during the runtime.
        this.olView = new ol.View({
            center: <any>center,
            zoom: this.zoom
        });
    this.olSource = new ol.source.OSM();
            this.olLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: this.olSource
            });
    this.olLayer.set('name', 'mainMap');
    // Initialize the map, on the element.
        let olMapOptions: olx.MapOptions = {
            target: 'ol-map',
            layers: [this.olLayer],
            view: this.olView
        };
   // Hide the controls?
        if (!this.isToolbarsVisible)
            olMapOptions.controls = [];

        // Create and initialize the map control.
        this.olMap = new ol.Map(olMapOptions);
```

This is where layers get added:

```
    /**
     * Adds a group, while also filling in any unfilled properties with default values.
     */
    addGroup(name: string, group: IAssetGroup) {

        if (!group.name)
            group.name = name || 'untitled';

        if (!group.vector)
            group.vector = new ol.source.Vector({});

        if (!group.layer)
            group.layer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: group.vector });

        if (!group.normalStyle)
            group.normalStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: 'black', width: 3 }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: 'black' })
            });

        if (!group.hoverStyle)
            group.hoverStyle = group.normalStyle;

        if (!group.selectedStyle)
            group.selectedStyle = group.normalStyle;

        if (!group.unselectedStyle)
            group.unselectedStyle = group.normalStyle;

        // Add the group to the collection.
        this.groups.push(group);

        // Add the layer to the map.
        this.olMap.addLayer(group.layer);

    }
```

These are URLs it requests:

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCu7KcUhw0AZ5GTlwQcNygUTgPU9e-1py4


 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate? 1shttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A40002%2FGigaclear%2FExplorer%2FMap%2F2d872130-da2a-481c-b226-32dc5ea153a8&4sAIzaSyCu7KcUhw0AZ5GTlwQcNygUTgPU9e-1py4&callback=_xdc_._181kcd&token=18200
```

Comment: please show us the url you used for the request, if you change the width height ratio of the output image you must change the width/height of the bounding box of the map.

Comment: also please delete your old question if you can't be bothered editing it to improve it

Comment: I am not trying to change the aspect ratio of the map, I am trying to preserve it. I have not set any width or height or bounding box with the map. Other software requirements demand that I specify an absolute width & height for the map div. I am just tring to get them right.

Answer (score 2):

You have fundamentally misunderstood how WMS maps work. You (or your code that you won't show here) makes a request to a server for the map image.

In that request there are 3 key parameters to control the aspect ratio of the map.

1. width and height of the map (i.e. the parameters you are playing with)
2. the bounding box of the map area, these are the real world coordinates of the lower left and top right hand corners of the map.

The WMS will go off and assemble all the data that falls within that bounding box and then render it onto an image with the width and height you asked for.

If your image and your bounding box have the same aspect ratio then all will be fine. If however you asked for a rectangular map on a square image it will look distorted when you get it back. The WMS specification specifically doesn't care about this as historically some systems using WMS had non-square pixels and wanted this result.

So if I request `http://astun-desktop:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=330&BBOX=-135.703125%2C23.642578125%2C-68.203125%2C52.646484375` I get

[image]

But if I ask for `http://astun-desktop:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=768&BBOX=-135.703125%2C23.642578125%2C-68.203125%2C52.646484375` (i.e. a square map)
I get

[image]

Comment: This is my code. I can't see any similarities at all between my code & your answer.

Comment: where do you add the layers to your map?

Comment: That is very complex. I have 9 different layers, one for each type of feature. I can add more of my code tomorrow.

Comment: alternatively look in the network tab of your debugger and see what the urls being request are

Comment: Am I using WMS maps?